# What word defines "slow moving and lingering?"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I've seen *lambent* used this way, but the definition doesn't quite match.  For example:

> She sensuously explored my chest/body with _____________ hands.

Where the word in the blank should mean "slow moving and lingering."

The use of *lambent* I saw was in *Dragonriders of PERN* when

> they watched the lambent sun ...

In that case it included the 'glistening/glowing' aspect as well as the slow setting/moving star applied.

Comment: *Loiter*? And saying *lambent* "doesn't quite match" *slow moving and lingering* is, I will grant you, technically true.

Comment: [Languorous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/languorous)?

Comment: Though it doesn't usually fit with "sensuously", "lethargic" is a possible term.

Answer (score 2):

**"languid"** is often used with this meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find one word that means that, unfortunately, but heres what i've got:

Meander can mean "to wander aimlessly".

To Dawdle essentially means to prolong something, the definition i see here is "take ones time".

Traipse apparently means "walk or move wearily or reluctantly", i'm pretty sure thats not what you're looking for though.

In the example you gave i think lambent essentially meant with a light touch and not in a forceful or "rigid" manner. The word sensual when used to describe exploring someone's body with ones hands generally (already) means slow. Though lambent also sort of seems to mean gentle, and in my opinion of rules out quick movement.

If you were trying to describe someone's walking, id honestly think that saying something like "He walked slowly, stopping frequently" would be lot better description than any single obscure word. I'm not sure exactly what you want to use lambent to describe, but, (i think) anything that is "mild" but for which intensity is not unheard of, could be described as lambent (gentle).

If the example is the sensual touching you were talking about, i think you're good to go. Sensual already essentially covers the bases, but lambent just goes a bit further in removing the possibility that youre talking about any sort of firm grasping, to me it says "make no mistake, this sensual exploration was done with a light touch". Possibly tickling slightly.

Answer (score 0):

*Caressing* may convey the sense you're seeking.

> She sensuously explored my chest/body with *caressing* hands.

From M-W:

[*caress*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caress): to touch (someone or something) in a gentle way